# Uber app crash when opened via deeplink multiple times

Tags: cordova, uber-api

Currently i am working on deeplinking to the Uber app from a cordova application.
The deeplink is working as expected on newer phones but on android 6.0 Uber crashes when the deeplink is called twice.

The following deeplink url is used:

```
https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=8AV0mBPupgZsue2ghtFfmd9sFV2wuNOg&pickup[formatted_address]=Rotterdam%20Centraal%20Station%2C%20Stationsplein%2C%20Rotterdam%2C%20Netherlands&pickup[latitude]=51.923674&pickup[longitude]=4.470496&dropoff[formatted_address]=Kinderhuissingel%2C%20Haarlem%2C%20Netherlands&dropoff[latitude]=52.386614&dropoff[longitude]=4.630431
```

The following steps to reproduce the error ( Android 6.0 ):

1. Open deeplink from cordova app
2. Wait for Uber to open
3. Press back button 2 times to go back to cordova app
4. Press deeplink agian from cordova app
5. Uber crashes with following error:

```
    02-19 09:38:41.056 18250-18250/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.ubercab, PID: 18250
       io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 1 exceptions occurred. 
           at com.ubercab.rx2.java.CrashOnErrorConsumer.onError(SourceFile:136)
           at com.ubercab.rx2.java.CrashOnErrorConsumer.onNext(SourceFile:115)
           at com.uber.autodispose.HalfSerializer.a(SourceFile:129)
           at com.uber.autodispose.AutoDisposingObserverImpl.onNext(SourceFile:79)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.e(SourceFile:200)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(SourceFile:252)
           at io.reactivex.android.FastPathScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(SourceFile:180)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
         ComposedException 1 :
        io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: arom
           at com.ubercab.rx2.java.CrashOnErrorConsumer.onError(SourceFile:136)
           at com.ubercab.rx2.java.CrashOnErrorConsumer.onNext(SourceFile:115)
           at com.uber.autodispose.HalfSerializer.a(SourceFile:129)
           at com.uber.autodispose.AutoDisposingObserverImpl.onNext(SourceFile:79)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.e(SourceFile:200)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(SourceFile:252)
           at io.reactivex.android.FastPathScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(SourceFile:180)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional.get() cannot be called on an absent value
           at jom.c(SourceFile:26)
           at arpl.a(SourceFile:137)
           at aroj.c(SourceFile:422)
           at aroj.a(SourceFile:388)
           at arom.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.ubercab.rx2.java.CrashOnErrorConsumer$1.a(SourceFile:69)
           at com.ubercab.rx2.java.CrashOnErrorConsumer.onNext(SourceFile:112)
           at com.uber.autodispose.HalfSerializer.a(SourceFile:129)
           at com.uber.autodispose.AutoDisposingObserverImpl.onNext(SourceFile:79)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.e(SourceFile:200)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(SourceFile:252)
           at io.reactivex.android.FastPathScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(SourceFile:180)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: This looks like a limitation of the Android 6.0. Can you consider upgrading your android version to the newer one? What is the practical possibility and percentage of cases of the user going twice back and forward on that android version? There is nothing that can be done to avoid this problem - Universal Links don't have additional parameters to cater for this type of problem on the specific Android version.

Comment: Currently 15.7% of our app users use Android 6.0 and lower. This is quite significant. The practical possibility of users using the universal link twice seems quite significant since how the app is set up (multiple universal link options offered). Would using the deeplink instead of the universal link solve this problem?

The Uber documentation specifies that universal links are supported by all Android devices...

Comment: You can try it with deeplink instead of UL -  maybe they work better on lover versions of the Android - so you can use one or another based on detected version.

Comment: Using deeplink fixes the problem in mine case

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is specific to using Universal Links on android 6.0 and lower. 
Resolved the problem by switching to deeplink (uber://).